# How to FullSimplify/Simplify an inequality while keep a variable isolated

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an inequality as follows

```
2^(1/2 (1 + 1/n)) > 0 && 
 t <= (2^(1/2 (-1 - 1/n) + n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) \[Pi]^((1/2)/n))/E
```

I want to simplify the `2^(1/2 (1 + 1/n)) > 0` to `True` using assumption that `n > 0`.

However, if I do the following,

```
2^(1/2 (1 + 1/n)) > 0 && 
  t <= (2^(1/2 (-1 - 1/n) + n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) \[Pi]^((1/2)/n))/E //
  FullSimplify[#, n > 0] &
```

I end up with

```
2^(1/2 (1 + 1/n)) E t <= 2^(n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) \[Pi]^((1/2)/n)
```

But I want to keep the `t` on one side of inequality. How can I do that.

Note the example is a bit simplified. I have a much complicated expression which I get from `Reduce` which I want to simplify, while keep `t` isolated on one side of inequalities.

Comment: Let us observe that `2^(1/2 (1 + 1/n)) ` is positive at any `n`. Therefore, you can safely replace your inequality by `t <= (2^(1/2 (-1 - 1/n) + n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) \[Pi]^((1/2)/n))/E &&n > 0`, and work with this one. You did not describe, though, what are you expecting to get from it? Limitations on what variable do you want to obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or

```
expr = 2^(1/2 (1 + 1/n)) > 0 && 
       t <= (2^(1/2 (-1 - 1/n) + n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) \[Pi]^((1/2)/n))/E;

expr // Refine[#, Assumptions -> n > 0] &

(*   t <= (2^(1/2 (-1 - 1/n) + n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) \[Pi]^(1/(2 n)))/E   *)
```

And with definite n

```
expr // Refine[#, n == 2] &

(*   t <= (2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(1/4))/E   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = 2^(1/2 (1 + 1/n)) > 0 && 
   t <= (2^(1/2 (-1 - 1/n) + n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) π^((1/2)/n))/E;

expr2 = ReplacePart[expr, 1 -> Simplify[expr[[1]], n > 0]]

(* t <= (2^(1/2 (-1 - 1/n) + n/2) n^(1 + 1/(2 n)) π^((1/2)/n))/E *)
```

Comment: Why do we need to clear "*"?

Comment: It clears the `Global\`` namespace to ensure that there are no old definitions laying around (i.e., for `n` or `t`) that might interfere with the subsequent code.